# Is there a way to open a new console from a program then cout into it?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to have a separate console window for my program that is already in a console. How would I be able to open this new console window then output to that specific console?

I've found ways to do it that work in windows using "cconsolelogger", but not for Linux.

Comment: Is your program a console already, or is it a window?

Comment: Its a console already.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "new console", you mean a terminal emulator window.

A terminal is a program like any other, so you start it like any other program. The only standard way in C++ to open another program is `std::system`, which executes a shell command. Here is an example of opening a terminal emulator:

```
std::system("xterm");
```

Note that it is not safe to pass arbitrary user provided input into the command, because it is vulnerable to shell injection.

The POSIX standard - that is followed by Linux operating systems in general - provides other, lower level tools to run another executable. In particular the `exec` family of functions allows executing another program without starting a sub process and without involving the shell.

Comment: Yeah i should've been more specific on what i meant by console. But how would i then cout into that xterm or gnome-terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `popen`.

You can choose the program to write command to it, for example:

```
gp = _popen("C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin\pgnuplot.exe", "w");
fprintf(gp, "set term png\n");
```